# .step function LTSPICE in multiple panes

Tags: frequency, simulation, ltspice

I am trying to simulate multiple different frequencies of a buck converter. I know how to step the parameters, but I would like the graphs in separate plot panes. Any clue on how to do that?

Two panes, but there is one signal so how do I separate the steps?

[image]

Comment: By "panes" do you mean seperate windows or areas within one window?

Comment: A pane is a window where you can put graphs in. So if you have two panes you have two places to put graphs in. Two different axis. It is a pretty common term. Don't know how to exactly explain it.

Comment: then I don't think that it is possible

Comment: So you want one pane per graph/param-step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to make it look right, but you can select a single step with an `@x` behind the node you are inspecting. The single line gets multiple colors, that is a bit strange, but maybe it can be fixed if you select the color yourself.

For example:

[image]

This feature is actually documented in the LTSpice Help under the Waveform Viewer -> Waveform Arithmetic topic:

> The step selection operator, '@' is useful when multiple simulation runs are available as in a .step, .temp, or .dc analysis. It selects the data from a specific run. For example, V(1)@3 would plot the data from the 3rd run no matter what steps where selected for plotting.

Comment: Nice one. It looks like it is still drawing all the steps (gets evident when you use large complex graphs where you can watch the single ones being painted over each other) but the data that is selected is the always the specific step. You can fix that by right click -> select steps and then selecting just anyone you like.